# $localStorage value got change with fabric js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I saving polygon value inside angular $localStorage .

Once fabric js draw the object . my $localStorage changed.

```
var arr = [{
        x: 81,
        y: 58
    }, {
        x: 221,
        y: 23
    }, {
        x: 247,
        y: 158
    }, {
        x: 100,
        y: 219
    }, {
        x: 81,
        y: 58
    }];

    if(!$localStorage.mask)
      $localStorage.mask = arr;
```

Is it a bug ?

Here the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQnOIat1x1kMYvI3Vp4j?p=preview)

Comment: It seems that AngularJS itself doesn't have any sort of $localStorage service. What localStorage do you use, https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage?

Comment: @misko321 based on plunker . I'm using ngStorage https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: And what sort of 'change' you experience? Does fabric.js adds something to your polygon array?

Comment: @misko321 you can see through the plunker i provide .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, FabricJS seems to modify the given points array for its internal purposes (i.e. offset), specifically in this piece of code (from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js):

```
...  
  //misko321: only for reference of what minX, minY, width and height are
  _calcDimensions: function() {

      var points = this.points,
          minX = min(points, 'x'),
          minY = min(points, 'y'),
          maxX = max(points, 'x'),
          maxY = max(points, 'y');

      this.width = (maxX - minX) || 0;
      this.height = (maxY - minY) || 0;

      this.minX = minX || 0,
      this.minY = minY || 0;
    },

  _applyPointOffset: function() {
      // change points to offset polygon into a bounding box
      // executed one time
      this.points.forEach(function(p) {
        p.x -= (this.minX + this.width / 2);
        p.y -= (this.minY + this.height / 2);
      }, this);
    },

...
```

Together with the fact that **ngStorage** observes for any changes to the added objects, it updates those modified (internally by **Fabric.js**) coordinates.

The cleanest solution that comes to my mind at the moment is to copy the *arr* object (ref. [Most elegant way to clone a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)) and send one of the objects to **ngStorage** and the other one to **FabricJS**.

Nevertheless, it would be nice, if **ngStorage** supported some sort of *freeze()* method, that would disable the **AngularJS** *watch* on this object, thus preventing it from further modifications.

Comment: did you try it . I have no luck because the problem at localStorage level . I end up switch to easeljs . thanks for your help .

Comment: No, I haven't tried that out, but if I understand the reason for the problem correctly (as I described) I think it should work.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many clone you have . Once you store in localStorage it will change the value . The problem at localStorage level . Unless you not using localStorage to store the other value for cloning purpose. In my case I just only use localStorage . Or maybe you right . Can you update the plunker ? Thanks